# 2-D arraylist resetting to 0s outside the while-loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am implementing the nondominated sorting subroutine in the NSGA-II algorithm. Below is the initial part of the code:

```
 public ArrayList<ArrayList<AttStrategy>> nondominatedSorting     
   (ArrayList<AttStrategy> StrategyPopulation, double max_rho_mal, double p_max) {

    int i = 0, p, q;
    int [] domination_count = new int[StrategyPopulation.size()];

    ArrayList<AttStrategy> dominated_strategies = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AttStrategy> dominating_strategies = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<AttStrategy>> dominated_strategies_list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<AttStrategy>> pareto_strategies = new ArrayList<>();

    while(i < StrategyPopulation.size()) {
        int j = 0;
        domination_count[StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId()] = 0;
        dominated_strategies.clear();
        for (j = i+1; j < StrategyPopulation.size(); j++){
            if (constraintDominated(StrategyPopulation.get(i), StrategyPopulation.get(j), max_rho_mal, p_max))
                dominated_strategies.add(StrategyPopulation.get(j));
            else if (constraintDominated(StrategyPopulation.get(j), StrategyPopulation.get(i), max_rho_mal, p_max))
                domination_count[StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId()] += 1;
        }
        if (domination_count[StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId()] == 0) {
            dominating_strategies.add(StrategyPopulation.get(i));
        }
        dominated_strategies_list.add(StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId(), dominated_strategies);

        //values getting stored in the arraylist
        System.out.println("Size of  " + StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId() + ":  " + dominated_strategies_list.get(i).size());
        i = i + 1;
    } //while-loop ends
    //values getting reset to 0.
    System.out.println("********Outside the loop*********");    
    for(i = 0; i < dominated_strategies_list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Size of  " + i + ":  " + dominated_strategies_list.get(i).size());
    }
    //.............................................
}
```

The problem that I am having is with the 2-D arraylist *dominated_strategies_list*. This arraylist is getting populated inside the while-loop, but once it is used outside the loop, all the values are resetting to 0. However, other arraylists, and arrays which are getting updated inside the loop are retaining their values outside the loop. Consequently, I cannot use this arraylist (*dominated_strategies_list*) in the later parts of the subroutine. Where am I making the mistake? Suggest some possible solutions.

Comment: very messy, please format your code and add some comments

Comment: ... or ignore the comment ... your choice and all depends on whether you need help or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every iteration you are clearing the referenced ArrayList, instead of that try creating a new ArrayList.

Here is a simplified example of you code demonstrating the mistake and the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args){        
    //Initialize stuff
    ArrayList<Integer> dom_strat = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dom_list = new ArrayList<>();
    dom_strat.add(5);
    dom_strat.add(3);

    //Add arrayList
    dom_list.add(dom_strat);

    //Print
    System.out.println("Before clear");
    for(ArrayList<Integer> aList:dom_list){
        for(Integer i: aList){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    //Clear referenced arrayList dom_list
    dom_strat.clear();
    //Print
    System.out.println("After clear");
    for(ArrayList<Integer> aList:dom_list){
        for(Integer i: aList){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }


     //Initialize again and apply the fix
    dom_strat = new ArrayList<>();
    dom_list = new ArrayList<>();
    dom_strat.add(5);
    dom_strat.add(3);

    //Add arrayList 
    dom_list.add(dom_strat);

    //Instead of clear, create a new arrayList
     dom_strat = new ArrayList<>();

     //Print
    System.out.println("After applying the fix");
    for(ArrayList<Integer> aList:dom_list){
        for(Integer i: aList){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I found out the error and worked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have only one `dominated_strategies` list that you fill and clear repeatedly.

The line

```
dominated_strategies_list.add(StrategyPopulation.get(i).getId(), dominated_strategies);
```

only adds a reference to this single list to `dominated_strategies_list`, it does not copy the `dominated_strategies` list, so on the next round through the loop, with `dominated_strategies.clear();` you throw away your previous result.

The solution is to replace

```
dominated_strategies.clear();
```

with

```
dominated_strategies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks!! I understood my mistake.